# ¿Porque mi proyecto de Java Web no termina de correr?

Tags: java-ee, maven, tomcat

Estoy usando NetBeans con Java Web, cuando creo el proyecto todo bien, pero cuando ejecuto el mismo carga un tiempo y al finalizar solo indica que la construcción termino con éxito pero no me arroja al navegador con el index.html. Trate de acceder a la ruta desde el navegador directamente pero no se encuentra el archivo. Como servidor estoy usando apache tomat 10 en el puerto 8090.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es dificil saberlo sin ver el `web.xml`

Comment: Hola Ruslan. El inconveniente lo solvente desde hace ya unos meses, de igual forma muchas gracias por responder, en efecto la configuracion de los xml estaban erroneas en cierto modo. Ahora mismo responderé como solucioné el inconveniente.

Answer (score 0):

Después de revisar el proyecto, los inconvenientes reales eran un conjunto de errores en los archivos xml.

1. Se tenia 2 servidores Apache montados en el mismo equipo, uno con el puerto `8090` y otro con el puerto `8095`. El archivo `server.xml` tendra esas configuraciones y en este caso estaban cruzados los puertos (El proyecto lo tenia el `8095`, y se estaba intentando acceder en el `8090`).
2. El servicio de apache estaba congelado, se reinicio y todo bien.

En resumen, verifiquen tener solo un servidor instalado, si es sumamente necesario tener mas de uno configurado, asegurense que el proyecto tenga el servidor correcto desde netbeans. Verifiquen los puertos desde `server.xml` y reinicien el servidor (desde `shutdown.bat` o `shutdown.sh`, estos archivos están en la raíz del server) y los servicios de apache.